# Vulkan и GLFW в полноэкранном режиме - мигание при выходе или переключении на рабочий стол

Tags: c++, glfw, vulkan

Использую Вулкан и GLFW для работы в полноэкранном режиме. Есть проблема - при выходе из приложения или просто переключении на рабочий стол возникает неприятный эффект "мигания" - сначала виден рабочий стол, потом на долю секунды снова экран приложения, потом снова рабочий стол. Выглядит это ужасно и интересует возможно ли это исправить. Заснял как это происходит:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrPo0KeOPsg

Update:

```
glfwInit();
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Vulkan 12", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), nullptr);

VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pipelineInfo = {};
    pipelineInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineInfo.stageCount = 2;
    pipelineInfo.pStages = shaderStages;
    pipelineInfo.pVertexInputState = &vertexInputInfo;
    pipelineInfo.pInputAssemblyState = &inputAssembly;
    pipelineInfo.pViewportState = &viewportState;
    pipelineInfo.pRasterizationState = &rasterizer;
    pipelineInfo.pMultisampleState = &multisampling;
    pipelineInfo.pColorBlendState = &colorBlending;
    pipelineInfo.layout = pipelineLayout;
    pipelineInfo.renderPass = renderPass;
    pipelineInfo.subpass = 0;
    pipelineInfo.basePipelineHandle = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
```

То что крутится в кадре:

```
void drawFrame() {
    uint32_t imageIndex;
    VkResult result = vkAcquireNextImageKHR(device, swapChain,  std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max(), imageAvailableSemaphore, VK_NULL_HANDLE, &imageIndex);

    if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR) {
        recreateSwapChain();
        return;
    }
    else if (result != VK_SUCCESS && result != VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to acquire swap chain image!");
    }

    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo = {};
    submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;

    VkSemaphore waitSemaphores[] = { imageAvailableSemaphore };
    VkPipelineStageFlags waitStages[] = { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT };
    submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = waitSemaphores;
    submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = waitStages;

    submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffers[imageIndex];

    VkSemaphore signalSemaphores[] = { renderFinishedSemaphore };
    submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

    if (vkQueueSubmit(graphicsQueue, 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to submit draw command buffer!");
    }

    VkPresentInfoKHR presentInfo = {};
    presentInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;

    presentInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
    presentInfo.pWaitSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

    VkSwapchainKHR swapChains[] = { swapChain };
    presentInfo.swapchainCount = 1;
    presentInfo.pSwapchains = swapChains;

    presentInfo.pImageIndices = &imageIndex;

    result = vkQueuePresentKHR(presentQueue, &presentInfo);

    if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR || result == VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR) {
        recreateSwapChain();
    }
    else if (result != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to present swap chain image!");
    }
}
```

Код вулкана в этом уроке:
http://vulkanapi.ru/2016/11/14/vulkan-api-%d1%83%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-29-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-hello-wo/

Comment: Есть подозрение, что любой вопрос по Vulkan рискует быть никогда не отвеченным. Без кода невозможно сказать, где проблема, а гигантские портянки в сотни строки никто не читает. Выложите код инициализации GLFW (вместе с `glfwWindowHint` и всем интересным), код отрисовки кадра (то, что крутится в цикле) и код инициализации `VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo` по возможности вырезав все неинтересные части (типа полей `sType`)

Comment: m9_psy, касательно и GLFW - там все стандартно, из базовых руководств. Обновил первый пост. Кстати, заметил интересную вещь - если запущена левая программа захвата видео с экрана (просто запущена, а не идет захват) - то этого мигания нет, все работает как надо.